# Delphi xe7 Android java.lang.illegalargumentexception:width and height must be > 0

Tags: android, delphi

I am new with Delphi XE and I am trying to build an Android app that can save an image or bitmap from camera. I run and deploy to my android device, and  click my `captureButton` from

```
procedure TForm1.captureButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
```

Then this message appears:

> java.lang.illegalargumentexception:width and height must be > 0.

Here is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.IOUtils,System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Winsoft.Android.ComPort, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Objects, FMX.Media, FMX.Platform,
  FMX.StdCtrls,FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Net, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Telephony,Androidapi.Helpers, FMX.StdActns,
  FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions, FMX.Ani, FMX.Effects, IdMessage, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase,
  IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase, IdSMTP, IdAttachmentFile;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    startKamera: TButton;
    stopKamera: TButton;
    frontKamera: TButton;
    backKamera: TButton;
    smsButton: TButton;
    settingsButton: TButton;
    connectButton: TButton;
    CameraComponent: TCameraComponent;
    kameraView: TImage;
    ActionList: TActionList;
    AComPort: TAComPort;
    Timer: TTimer;
    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
    captureButton: TButton;
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    Label1: TLabel;
    dropdown: TSpeedButton;
    popup: TRectangle;
    ShadowEffect1: TShadowEffect;
    popupAnimation: TFloatAnimation;
    SMTP: TIdSMTP;
    msg: TIdMessage;
    Email: TButton;
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;

    procedure startKameraClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure stopKameraClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure frontKameraClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure backKameraClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CameraComponentSampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
      const ATime: Int64);
    procedure smsButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComportError(ComPort: TAComPort; E: EComError;
      var Action: TComAction);
    procedure connectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure settingsButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clikdropdown(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EmailClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure captureButtonClick(Sender: TObject);


  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure AmbilGambar;
    procedure SendImage(const Comment, AImage: String);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    img: TBitmap;
    procedure showpopup;
    procedure hidepopup;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses Unit2;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.AmbilGambar;
begin
  CameraComponent.SampleBufferToBitmap(kameraView.Bitmap, True);
  kameraView.SendToBack;
end;

procedure TForm1.backKameraClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CameraComponent.Active := False;
  CameraComponent.Kind := FMX.Media.TCameraKind.BackCamera;
  CameraComponent.Active := True;
  hidepopup;
end;

procedure TForm1.CameraComponentSampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
  const ATime: Int64);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, AmbilGambar);
end;

procedure TForm1.captureButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp:TBitmap;
begin
  //bmp:= kameraView.Bitmap;
  //bmp := kameraView.Bitmap;
    ///bmp.SetSize(200,200);
    //bmp.SaveToFile('/sdcard/Pictures/tes.bmp');
  kameraView.Bitmap.Create;
  kameraView.Bitmap.SetSize(200,200);
  //kameraView.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);
  kameraView.Bitmap.SaveToFile(GetHomePath+PathDelim+'Documents'+PathDelim+'Pictures'+PathDelim+ 'e.png');
    kameraView.Free;
  hidepopup;
end;
```

How can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this line:

```
kameraView.Bitmap.Create;
```

When you read from the `TImage.Bitmap` property, it creates a `TBitmap` (if not already created) that is owned by `TImage`.  You do not need to call `Create()` manually in that situation.  Only when you are creating a new `TBitmap` to assign to your own variable, eg:

```
bmp:= TBitmap.Create;
```

Comment: I have removed this code => kameraView.Bitmap.Create; as you have suggest,,                                                                                       procedure TForm1.captureButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp:TBitmap;
begin

  //bmp:= TBitmap.Create;
  kameraView.Bitmap.SetSize(200,200);
  //kameraView.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);
  kameraView.Bitmap.SaveToFile(GetHomePath+PathDelim+'Documents'+PathDelim+'Pictures'+PathDelim+ 'e.bmp');
 and appear saving bitmap failed:

Comment: Are you actually assigning an image to `kameraView.Bitmap` before saving? `captureButtonClick()` does not actually capture anything, it merely saves whatever the current image is. So you have to click on `backKamera` first to actually acquire the image from the camera, and then click on `captureButton` to save it. Is that really how you want your Form to work? BTW, `GetHomePath+PathDelim+'Documents'+PathDelim+'Pictures'+PathDelim+ 'e.png'` should be changed to `TPath.Combine(TPath.GetPicturesPath, 'e.png')` instead.

Comment: 'TPath.Combine(TPath.GetPicturesPath, 'e.png')' solved with 'System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPicturesPath, 'e.png')'. but i dont understand with assigning an image to 'kameraView.Bitmap'

Comment: hi @Remy Lebeau,,,I am now able to save picture to DCIM directory by using Delphi xe8 in my college lab ,using xe8 library in [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXPhotoLibrary.AddImageToSavedPhotosAlbum)....